# rtsp client code not working

Tags: java, sockets

I am facing problem in Java socket communication, I am running Live555 Media Server and one small app (some what similar to proxy server code, referred one online code snippet) in one machine, and also created one client code and running in my laptop. All  machines are in same network. When I send RTSP Command from client to proxy, It is receiving properly and it is redirecting that received command to Live555 server and its getting back proper response but the response is not receiving in client. Help me to fix this problem and also suggest me some doc link to understand the problem.

here is my proxy code,

```
public class TestProxyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        String host = "127.0.0.1";
        int serverPort = 8554;
        int proxyPort = 5555;

        System.out.println("Starting proxy for " + host + ":" + serverPort
                + " on port " + proxyPort);

        runServer(host, serverPort, proxyPort);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

public static void runServer(String host, int sProt, int pPort) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(pPort);

    final byte[] request = new byte[1024];
    byte[] replay = new byte[1024];

    while(true) {

        Socket server = null, client = null;

        try {

            client = ss.accept();

            final InputStream fromClient = client.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream toClient = client.getOutputStream();

            // for Live555
            try {
                server = new Socket(host, sProt);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(toClient);
                out.print("Proxy can not connect to Live555 on host " + host + " with the port " + sProt + "\n");
                out.flush();
                client.close();
                continue;
            }

            final InputStream fromServer = server.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream toServer = server.getOutputStream();

            Thread t = new Thread() {

                public void run() {

                    int bytesRead;

                    try {

                        String ClientMSG;
                        while((bytesRead = fromClient.read(request)) != -1) {
                            toServer.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
                            ClientMSG = new String(request, 0, bytesRead);
                            System.err.println("From Client : " + ClientMSG);
                            toServer.flush();
                        }

                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        try {toServer.close();} catch(IOException ioe){}
                    }                       
                }
            };

            t.start();

            int bytesRead;

            try {
                String toCMSG;
                while((bytesRead = fromServer.read(replay)) != -1) {

                    toClient.write(replay, 0, bytesRead);
                    toCMSG = new String(replay, 0, bytesRead);
                    System.err.println("Response from Live555 " + toCMSG);
                    toClient.flush();
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                toClient.close();
//                  e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if(server != null)
                server.close();

            if(client != null)
                client.close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

and client code is here,

```
    public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        String host = "192.168.1.9";
        // int serverPort = 8554;
        int proxyPort = 5555;

        System.out.println("Starting Client to connect proxy on " + host + ":" + " with port " + proxyPort);

        runServer(host, proxyPort);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void runServer(String host, int sPort) throws IOException {

    final byte[] request = new byte[1024];
    final byte[] reply = new byte[1024];

    while (true) {

        Socket server = null;

        try {

            // for Proxy
            try {
                server = new Socket(host, sPort);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Proxy can not connect to ProxyServer on host " + host + " with the port " + sPort + "\n");
                continue;
            }

            final InputStream fromServer = server.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream toServer = server.getOutputStream();

            int bytesRead;

            try {

                String RtspMSG = "DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.9:8554/free.ts RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 2\r\n\r\n";
                // while((bytesRead = fromClient.read(RtspMSG.getBytes()))
                // != -1) {
                toServer.write(RtspMSG.getBytes(), 0, RtspMSG.length());
                System.err.println("Sent : " + RtspMSG);
                toServer.flush();
                // }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    toServer.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                }
            }

            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {

                    int bytesRead;

                    try {
                        String response = null;
                        System.err.println("----------------------------------");
                        while ((bytesRead = fromServer.read(reply)) != -1) {

                            response = new String(reply, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                        System.err.println("Response from Proxy : "
                                + response);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        try {
                            fromServer.close();
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                        }
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (server != null)
                server.close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Have you done any tests? Have you tried without proxy?

Comment: without proxy i have tested and its working fine but that client code is not usable, because its just one way code.

Comment: Have you tried not closing "toServer" until all is done? And also cumulating the input from Server, instead of replacing the String for each line. You'll only get the last line always. You might want to try a StringBuilder.

Comment: bit confused (correct me if i am wrong), on client, if any exception occurs then only i am closing toServer. and in client side i am not at all getting any msg from server.

Comment: Well you should always put in some indicator of an exception being thrown. Keeping the catch-blocks empty will end up in swallowed exceptions. I recommend using a logging framework rather than `System.out`.

Comment: is that causing problem?

Comment: That is possible at least.

Comment: yes that helped, and also i have found that in client side, inside thread block, while loop is not terminating, if i print the response string in the loop only, then its displaying proper response, but its not terminating. how to fix this?

Comment: am i doing anything wrong in reading block? yesterday even i have tested in server side also its not coming out from Thread's while loop block. how to fix this?

Comment: any solution for my problem? its not coming out from while loop in both server and client code module. Help me to fix this please